# Get correct time

Tags: c#, wpf

I am getting the current time and trying to split it into two separate variables.
I want the time to be in 12 hours not 24

When i do this the first and second variable are the same. How can i fix this?

```
int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour % 12;
if (hour == 0) hour = 12;
```

then,

```
FirstDigitHour = hour / 10;
secondDigitHour = hour %  10;
```

the time here is 6 pm so FirstDigitHour & secondDigitHour both = 6

the first digit should equal 0

Comment: I don't understand the question... I tryed it here and FirstDigitHour is 0, and secondDigitHour is 6, when the input hour is 6. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to format the time for display, I would advise you use the proper format string:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh tt")
```

Which is the time in 2-digit 12-hour format (*hh*) with AM/PM (*tt*)

See the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't this satisfy your need better

> var x = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh");

it returns a string with hours in 12 hour format ( e.g. "01" or "02" ... "11" "12" )

Then you can just get the first and second digit like so

> int firstDigit = Convert.ToInt32(x[0].ToString());
>
> int secondDigit = Convert.ToInt32(x[1].ToString());

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine for me.

```
        int hr = 18; // 6pm
        int hour = hr % 12;
        if (hour == 0)
            hour = 12;
        int fd = hour/10;
        int ld = hour%10;
```

in this case I have `fd = 0` and `ld = 6`.

See [it run](http://ideone.com/81LDl).

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a second digit first...  if DateTime.Now.Hour > 10. Then you have it.